# Difference between java downloads

Tags: java, installation

What is the difference between these two downloadable versions of Java EE:

java_ee_sdk-6u3-jdk7-windows-ml.exe
java_ee_sdk-6u3-jdk7-windows.exe

---

Comment: Roughly 7.05MB. :)

Answer (score 26, accepted):

The ml release is multilingual. It depends upon what you are trying to accomplish to determine what version you should use. If you don't mind the extra space and you think you'll need localization for a different language, pick the ml. Otherwise the standard one will do fine.

Answer (score 2):

> Note – In all cases, the *-ml.zip bundles in the table are multilingual versions of the .
>   product

http://glassfish.java.net/docs/3.1/installation-guide.pdf