# difference between java downloads

Tags: java, oracle, jakarta-ee, download

Once answered the question about the difference between this two versions

**java_ee_sdk-6u3-jdk7-windows-ml.exe

java_ee_sdk-6u3-jdk7-windows.exe**
(ml means Multi Languaje)
in this stackoverflow question --> [Difference between java downloads](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6876287/difference-between-java-downloads)

I would like to know now, what is the difference between this two downloads
**java_ee_sdk-6u4-jdk7-windows-ml.exe

java_ee_sdk-6u4-web-jdk7-windows-ml.exe**

by the way, what is *web-profile*?

Answer (score 2):

The web profile is a lightweight version of the full Java EE stack. It only includes some parts of the full Java EE stack, specifically targeted at building web applications.

See http://jaxenter.com/introducing-the-java-ee-web-profile-36201.html for an introduction.

Comment: Thanks a lot JB Nizet  
in addition, what is also not said is that you need to have before installed a version of JRE or JDK(including JRE) to be able to install any JEE  
what a mess!!!