# What does the ML stands for in java_ee_sdk-6u4-unix-ml.sh?

Tags: jakarta-ee, sdk

What does the `ML` word stands for in `java_ee_sdk-6u4-unix-ml.sh` file ? Which version corresponds the most to Mac OS X Mountain Lion `java_ee_sdk-6u4-unix-ml.sh` or `java_ee_sdk-6u4-unix.sh` ?

[Web page of this file](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javaee/downloads/java-ee-sdk-6u3-downloads-439814.html).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

["ml" stands for multi-lingual](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6876338/981049).

As for installing onto MacOS, look for a downloadable file that has "`macos`" as part of the filename. The file is likely to be a disk image file with a "`.dmg`" extension.

Answer (score 0):

In that case ml stands for Multi-Language.